# How to fix tensor dimensionality error on pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

Dimensionality error with PyTorch tensors.

I have a .txt corpus which contains a shakespeare play. I need to build a simple recurrent neural network that takes in one letter from the corpus and outputs the next letter accurately (as much as possible). the model should have only one input unit and one output unit for every letter that appears in the corpus. The model should have 3 layers: 1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output layer.

Here is my code:

```
:import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

# Load the corpus
with open('shakespeare.txt', 'r') as file:
    corpus = file.read()

# Create a set of unique characters in the text
chars = sorted(set(text))

# Create a dictionary to map characters to indices and vice versa
char_to_idx = {char: idx for idx, char in enumerate(chars)}
idx_to_char = {idx: char for idx, char in enumerate(chars)}

# Convert the text to a sequence of character indices
indices = [char_to_idx[char] for char in text]

# Define the RNN model
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        output, hidden = self.rnn(embedded.unsqueeze(1), hidden)
        output = self.fc(output.squeeze(1))
        return output, hidden


# Training loop
def train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        hidden = None
        for inputs, targets in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs, hidden = model(inputs.unsqueeze(1), hidden)
            loss = criterion(outputs.view(-1, len(chars)), targets.view(-1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

# Hyperparameters
hidden_size = 128
num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.01
chunk_size = 10000

# Create the RNN model
model = RNN(len(chars), hidden_size, len(chars))

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Create TensorDataset and DataLoader
train_data = torch.tensor(indices[:-chunk_size])
target_data = torch.tensor(indices[chunk_size:])
dataset = TensorDataset(train_data, target_data)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1)

# Train the model
train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, n
```

I'm getting this error and it has to do with the 'def forward(self, x, hidden):' step

```
AssertionError: RNN: Expected input to be 2-D or 3-D but received 4-D tensor
```

How can I fix this? I've tried the following but none of them worked:

```
def forward(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    output, hidden = self.rnn(x.unsqueeze(1), hidden)
    output = self.fc(output.squeeze(1))
    return output, hidden
```

And

```
def forward(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    x = x.unsqueeze(0)  # Add an extra dimension at the beginning
    output, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)
    output = self.fc(output.squeeze(0))
    return output, hidden
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`embedded.unsqueeze(1)`

in

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        ...

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        output, hidden = self.rnn(embedded.unsqueeze(1), hidden)
        output = self.fc(output.squeeze(1))
        return output, hidden
```

gives you a `Tensor` object of size `[1, 1, 1, 128]`, which has 4 dimensions - this is why torch is complaining. You can pass `embedded` directly into `self.rnn()` without the unsqueezing.

However, running the code with this update will return a `RuntimeError` - after looking up the official [`PyTorch`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html) tutorial, I have adapted your code in `class RNN(nn.Module)` and `train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs)`. Now the code runs without error.

PS: As you can see, I have used a `shakespeare.txt` file which I found on GitHub, assuming it is the same as you are using.

```
import urllib.request

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader



# Load shakespeare.txt
url = "https://github.com/brunoklein99/deep-learning-notes/blob/master/shakespeare.txt"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as fin:
    # Save locally if desired.
    text = fin.read().decode("utf-8")


# Load the corpus - Code used by OP
# with open('shakespeare.txt', 'r') as file:
#     corpus = file.read()

# Create a set of unique characters in the text
chars = sorted(set(text))

# Create a dictionary to map characters to indices and vice versa
char_to_idx = {char: idx for idx, char in enumerate(chars)}
idx_to_char = {idx: char for idx, char in enumerate(chars)}

# Convert the text to a sequence of character indices
indices = [char_to_idx[char] for char in text]

# Define the RNN model
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        output, _ = self.rnn(embedded)
        output = self.fc(output.squeeze(1))
        return output

# Training loop
def train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        hidden = None
        iter = 0
        for inputs, targets in train_loader:
            iter += 1
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs.unsqueeze(1))
            loss = criterion(outputs.view(-1, len(chars)), targets.view(-1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()



# Hyperparameters
hidden_size = 128
num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.01
chunk_size = 10000

# Create the RNN model
model = RNN(len(chars), hidden_size, len(chars))

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Create TensorDataset and DataLoader
train_data = torch.tensor(indices[:-chunk_size])
target_data = torch.tensor(indices[chunk_size:])
dataset = TensorDataset(train_data, target_data)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1)

# Train the model
train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs)
```

Comment: thank you! When you ran this, did it take a long time to run the def train() function? Because mine has been jumping between optimizer.step() and loss.backward()for 25mins now...

Comment: @karak87rt0 yes it takes indeed a very long time, that's because you're performing backpropagation after every single row!  When you increase your `batch_size` (for example to 10000) your algorithm trains much faster.

Comment: @karak87rt0 if my answer helped you resolve the problem you were experiencing, I would greatly appreciate it if you could accept my answer :)